# Form data get converted into uppercase at the time of saving

Tags: forms

I have big drupal form and when the form get save, at that time I need all form data should be converted into upper case and then should get save.

Comment: drupal form means if u r used  web form

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code you wrote, for which you want to write better code, or you want to understand why it doesn't work, but you do not show the code you are using, or the part of the code that is relevant for the question. See [Help Center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for details.

Comment: @SenthilKumar : What are you trying tell ? Please be descriptive so that others can understand ? Avoid single letters like 'u' , 'r'.. Please check your grammar too.. Are you trying to ask user whether he is using web form ?

Comment: No, I am not using webform. Form is created by fieldgroup module.

Comment: Is it a Content Type form ? Can you share more information like screenshot or path of the form so that we can understand better ?

Comment: yes it is content type form which is created using field group module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alter node data before saving using [hook_node_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) which will be implemented in a custom module... You can read values and change it to uppercase using [strtoupper](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php) php function...

OR

You can simply use [Simple Field Formatter module](https://drupal.org/project/simple_field_formatter)

Project page says

> The Simple Field Formatter module allows site administrators to easily
>   control the display of field values with following features

Features:

Prepend the field value with specified text/HTML

Append the field value with specified text/HTML

Reverse the Field Value

Trim the Field Value

Convert the field value to lowercase letters

**Convert the field value to uppercase letters**

Convert the first character of the field value to uppercase

Convert the first character of each word in the field value to uppercase (7.x-1.x-dev)

Replace some characters with some other characters in the field value (7.x-1.x-dev)

Link the field value to node(7.x-2.x-dev)